# Import CSV Validation in PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I am trying to upload/import CSV into SQL server with some basic validation such as **CSV headers should contain 'SecurityID' and 'SecurityID' value can NOT be NULL and has NUMERIC value**. I'm having some issue validating headers part and stuck. Below is my code from **functions.php**. For clarity I've removed DB insert/update code as I am not getting that far.

```
    if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

            $filetempname=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
            $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];

            $csv_mimetypes = array(
                            'text/csv',
                            'text/plain',
                            'application/csv',
                            'text/comma-separated-values',
                            'application/excel',
                            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                            'application/vnd.msexcel',
                            'text/anytext',
                            'application/octet-stream',
                            'application/txt',
                        );
            $expectedHeaders = array(
                'SecurityID'
            );

            $requiredFields = array(
                'SecurityID'
            );

            $firstLine = true;

            if (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csv_mimetypes)) 
            {
                if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
                {
                $file = fopen($filetempname, "r");
                #echo $file;

                while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {   
                    foreach($getData as $row)
                    {
                        if($firstLine)
                        {
var_dump($expectedHeaders);
                            //Set the headers:
                            $firstLine = false;
var_dump($getData);
                            $headers = array_flip($getData);

                            // Validate the headers:
                            if($headers !== $expectedHeaders)
                            {
                                echo "Invalid headers. Aborting import.";
                            }
                            Continue;
                        }

                        foreach($requiredFields as $requiredKey)
                        {
                            $value = $row[$headers[$requiredKey]];
                            // '0' will also match as empty(), although it is a valid value:
                            if(empty($value) && $value != '0' && is_numeric($value))
                            {
                                echo "Row {$requiredKey} may not be empty or has to be numeric. Aborting import.";
                            }
                        }
                        fclose($file);  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                window.location = \"indexd.php\"
                </script>";
            }
        }
```

Trying to upload/validate CSV I get below errors. IIS webserver logs doesn't give me anything..:

```
Invalid headers. Aborting import.
```

var_dump($getData); gives me below:

```
array(15) { 
[0]=> string(14) "DataProviderID" 
[1]=> string(8) "FamilyID" 
[2]=> string(10) "FamilyName" 
[3]=> string(10) "SecurityID" 
[4]=> string(4) "Name" 
[5]=> string(10) "PrimaryRic" 
[6]=> string(13) "Administrator" 
[7]=> string(16) "IsAdminEULocated" 
[8]=> string(21) "IsAdminOnEsmaRegister" 
[9]=> string(25) "IsBenchmarkOnEsmaRegister" 
[10]=> string(26) "IsBenchmarkOnAdminRegister" 
[11]=> string(23) "HasEUListedFundTracking" 
[12]=> string(25) "HasEUListedFutureOrOption" 
[13]=> string(20) "IsAdminPre2016Active" 
[14]=> string(24) "IsBenchmarkPre2018Active" 
}
```

var_dump($expectedHeaders); gives me below:

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> string(10) "SecurityID" 
}
```

My CSV file for testing is as below:

```
DataProviderID,FamilyID,FamilyName,SecurityID,Name,PrimaryRic,Administrator,IsAdminEULocated,IsAdminOnEsmaRegister,IsBenchmarkOnEsmaRegister,IsBenchmarkOnAdminRegister,HasEUListedFundTracking,HasEUListedFutureOrOption,IsAdminPre2016Active,IsBenchmarkPre2018Active
2,MSCI,MSCI Main Indices - Americas,17912,NORTH AMERICA IMI-664176,.dMINA000I0PUS,MSCI Limited,1,1,0,99,99,99,99,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I included some `var_dump`'s so you could see what your code does. When something doesn't work as expected ALWAYS verify your variables ("Does it hold the value I expect it does?"):

```
// [...]
$expectedHeaders = array(
    'SecurityID'
);

var_dump($expectedHeaders);
// Will print array(
//    0 => (string) 'SecurityID'
// )

// [...] while foreach etc

//Set the headers:
$firstLine = false;

var_dump($getData);
// Will print array(
//    0 => (string) 'DataProviderID'
//    1 => (string) 'FamilyID'
//    2 => (string) 'FamilyName'
//    3 => (string) 'SecurityID'
//    etc
// );

$headers = array_flip($getData);

var_dump($headers);
// Will print array(
//    (string) 'DataProviderID' => 0
//    (string) 'FamilyID'       => 1
//    (string) 'FamilyName'     => 2
//    (string) 'SecurityID'     => 3
//    etc
// )

// Validate the headers:
if($headers !== $expectedHeaders) 
{
    // Will always get into this if, because as you can see
    // from the var_dumps, $expectedHeaders will never be 
    // equal to $headers - nor equal to $getData
    echo "Invalid headers. Aborting import.";
}
```

A possible solution for your if-statement below. [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) will give the values that are both in `$getData` as in `$expectedHeaders`. If `$getData` contains more headers, those are wiped-out by `array_intersect` resulting in the same count (assuming order doesn't matter). If `$getData` has missing headers, the count of that intersection will be less than the count of `$expectedHeaders`.

```
if (
    count(array_intersect($getData, $expectedHeaders)) 
    != count($expectedHeaders)
) {
    // Wrong CSV format error
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with var_dump in the code and output.

Comment: Did you also read the rest of my answer? `$expectedHeaders` will never  equals `$headers` as I demonstrated in the code I typed within my answer. I already knew (from experience and other info you gave in your question) the output `var_dump` would give, so I typed those within the code of my answer.

Comment: Yes read it. making changes to test it now as per your suggestion.

Comment: Ah so. I exctually meant that more for debugging in general, for yourself and for the next time you run into problems ;)